# query that returns the values from column1 that occur only one time

Tags: sql, database, plsql

Let's have a table like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      column1        |     column2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          |         1234     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          |         6666     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          |         7777     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          B          |         1234     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          B          |         6666     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          C          |         6666     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          D          |         1234     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want a query that returns C and D.

I want a query that returns the values from column1 that occur less than 2 times (edited: after I have "only one time").

I am using plSQL.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY columnNeeded
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with distinct:

```
SELECT column1 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY column1
HAVING COUNT(column1) < 2;
```

Comment: Thank for your quick answer, but when I run, the result is : "not a GROUP BY expression"

Answer (score 1):

The column list in `select` should match with column list in `GROUP BY`, You should not use `*` when you are specifying individual columns in `GROUP BY` or else you need to specify all the `columns` in `group by` clause.

```
SELECT column1 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY column1
HAVING COUNT(column1) < 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine, but you can't select all columns (only that appear in `group by` clause unless...). So you need `max(column2)` that is in any case unique :

```
SELECT columnNeeded, max(column2)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY columnNeeded
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CTE`.

```
;WITH yourtable AS
(SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY column1) AS col1count FROM mytable)
SELECT column1, column2
FROM yourtable
WHERE col1count = 1
```

Output

```
column1 column2
C       6666
D       1234
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2fd7f/1/0

Comment: You don't need CTE; you can use max(column2)

Comment: Its an alternative answer that removes the need for `GROUP BY`, you don't NEED to use a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do, is group by column1 and then filter your results with the "having" clause, just like this:

```
WITH MY_TABLE AS(
  SELECT 'A' AS COLUMN1, 1234 AS COLUMN2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS COLUMN1, 6666 AS COLUMN2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS COLUMN1, 7777 AS COLUMN2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS COLUMN1, 1234 AS COLUMN2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS COLUMN1, 6666 AS COLUMN2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' AS COLUMN1, 6666 AS COLUMN2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D' AS COLUMN1, 1234 AS COLUMN2 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT    COLUMN1 
FROM      MY_TABLE
GROUP BY  COLUMN1
HAVING    COUNT(COLUMN1) < 2;
```

Comment: How your answer is different than what is posted below by @apomene. Did you read all the answer before contributing from yourside.